# How can I enlarge videos using webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to have a function in my android app where I can enlarge videos to full screen from web view. But so far it doesn't work. Other apps seem to have this but I don't know how they do it. Thanks for your replies.

```
private void initWebView() {
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0);

        /* 处理后退键 */
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mHistory != null
                        && webView.canGoBack()) {
            if (mHistory.size() > 1) {
                mHistory.remove(0);
                webView.loadUrl(mHistory.get(0));
                return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
            }
        });
      }
webView.loadUrl(“http://….”);
```

Comment: is it required to use a webview only. we can scale the videoview

Comment: Currently I only use webview. Later videoview might be a possibility but currently I need to use webview. thanks

Comment: can you give me the example app name so that i can see what exactly is that you want cause there is no screen shot also